# upgrading WP8.0 app to WP8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am working on my project (app) from 2-3 months on Windows Phone 8

and yesterday i saw the new features and controls of the Windows Phone 8.1 development

and I would like to add to my existing app those new **features**

so is there anyway to **Convert** or **Upgrade** my project from 8.0 to 8.1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your solution in Visual Studio 2013,
right click the Windows Phone 8.0 project in the Solution Explorer,
then click Retarget to Windows Phone 8.1.

Be careful, and backup your original project, this action cannot be undone!